# Overloading << operator to insert into a vector

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading

I have found many solutions that overload the output stream operator to print out a vector.  I need to do the opposite.  Something like,

```
vector<string> v;
  v << "String1" << "String2" << "String3" << "String4" << "String5";
```

I have this code, which only adds the first string.  I understand why that is, but I can't figure out how to add the other strings.

```
template<typename T, typename T2>
vector<T> operator<<(vector<T>& v1, T2 s) {
    v1.push_back(s);
    return v1;
}
```

Comment: Return a reference `vector<T>& operator...`

Comment: Please don't. The 'streams' overloading is bad enough. If you must use an operator, use + and - for add and delete.

Comment: I Figured it out.  I just needed to return vector<T>& instead of vector<T>

Answer (score 7):

In your function, you are returning a copy of the input `vector`. I am surprised your compiler didn't warn you about using a temporary object as an argument where a reference is expected.

Change the return type to a reference.

```
template<typename T, typename T2>
vector<T>& operator<<(vector<T>& v1, T2 s) {
//      ^^^
    v1.push_back(s);
    return v1;
}
```

Comment: You are exactly right.  I figured that out on my own, but thanks for the advice.  Compiler is VS 2010 - I was surprised it didn't warn me either.